# Is sorting a vb.net class faster than using excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, sorting, office-interop

Despite how I got here, I found sending the data to excel to use the excel built in sort was much faster `Excel.Range.Sort ("sending it to Excel")`.  In my head I had assumed that excel was probably written in a more efficient language and the efficiency of the sort of a large set of data outweighed the small COM overhead for transferring the data.

Now I am using a custom class I was wondering if a custom sort `IComparable` is faster.  Has anyone compared the two?

Comment: you cant sort a class/class object - it is just one thing.  There must be some collection of stuff somewhere that gets sorted.  No one can say why it might be slow without seeing the code.

Comment: Its not slow anymore I already dropped the 2 dim array, and yes I know I can sort the class.  I am trying to see if sorting a class is faster than sending data to excel to sort.

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: If no one has already raced their two horses, I will

Comment: but, *my* horse (my code) is likely to be different than *your* horse.  the results are inconclusive

Comment: Points: 1) the builtin .Net sorting is as fast as anything in Excel (both are written in C++), and 2) Both the Excel COM Interop and the Excel visual API methods have *significant* overhead.  You'll be much better off sorting things yourself.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can write good code in any language and bad code in any language. Just because the same language is used doesn't mean the same algorithm was used. Your point is moot. Moreover, there were other languages involved than just C++  to write .net. Some of it was even written in C#

Comment: @Jeroen Your argument is facile and irrelevant.  The fact is that if the data is already in the range it is usually faster to use the Excel.Range.Sort.  If not, then it is usually faster to sort them yourself using the .Net library, or even with VBA. If you've got any relevant facts, I would certainly listen to them.  Otherwise, I am going to prefer my 2 decades of experience actually doing and measuring these things over your opinion and rhetoric.

Comment: @RBarryYoung you are calling my argument superficial yet you fail to give us anything evidence based, so at this point it's all your opinion anyway which is just as "facile". Precisely why I already stated (see below) that I flagged this question as needing to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.  I take it to mean you are comparing two techniques:

1. Holding your data in a spreadsheet, and calling Excel.Range.Sort ("sending it to Excel")
2. Holding your data in a Visual Basic array, and sorting it with your own code, using loops and comparisons written in VBA.

Technique 1 will be much faster.

Comment: The technique 2 is the old technique.  Maybe it was not worth mentioning how I got to where I am at.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Both Excel data exchanges and visual methods like `Range.Sort` have significant overhead of their own.  I have almost always been able to match or beat Excel *even* with VBA, *especially* if the data was not already in the range to be sorted.  If the data is in VB.net, it's no contest at all.

Comment: Neither answer nor comment state any empirical evidence to validate the claim being made. Hence why I voted to close this question as attracting mostly opinion-based answers...

Comment: @Jeroen you are correct.  i will have to concede to plutonix point.  I was just hoping someone had already done this.

Comment: @RBarry I will agree that a major contributor to run time will be made up of moving the data to/from cells.  I think if the data are already in the cells, use Range.Sort, and if they're already in an array, sort it yourself.  Moving the data back and forth just to sort it is never going to be a better idea.